# Not able to print custom log level on stream handlers using logging module in python3.6

Tags: python, logging

Below is the function in `__init__.py` file which means this part of code always run when code is executed

```
import logging
def log_setup():

    logging.TRACE = 5
    logging.addLevelName(5, 'TRACE')
    def trace(obj, message, *args, **kws):
        obj.log(logging.TRACE, message, *args, **kws)
    logging.Logger.trace = trace
    logging.trace = trace
    root = logging.getLogger("TEST")
    root.setLevel(5)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setFormatter(f)
    ch.setLevel(5)
    root.handlers = []
    root.addHandler(ch)
```

I am having below code in one of the library say xyz.py

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger("TEST."+__name__)
if log.trace:
    print("***ELLO***", log.getEffectiveLevel())
    print("***ELLO***", log.isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG))
    print("***ELLO***", log.isEnabledFor(logging.TRACE))
    log.trace("Hey Statement printed")
```

When I am calling via script, I am not able to get the log.trace printed. Interestingly, For log.isEnabledFor(logging.TRACE) is always returning False.

Not sure what i am missing here

Below is the output

```
***ELLO*** 10
***ELLO*** True
***ELLO*** False
```

Comment: I didn't get it. How `__name__` is having debug level.

Comment: Hum, I guess I made a mistake, sorry.

Comment: Can't reproduce. If I take your code, enhance it by defining the formatter in `log_setup()` (e.g. `f = logging.Formatter('{message}', style='{')` and calling `log_setup()` in `__init__.py` on module level, I get `Hey Statement printed` in the terminal. Double-check the code, maybe you forgot to call `log_setup()`?

Comment: @hoefling: Script from where I was calling was having call as `root = logging.getLogger("TEST")`. I changed this command to `root = logging.getLogger("TEST."+__name)` and it worked. Not sure why

Answer (score 1):

There is not TRACE log level in python unless you have created a custom handler by yourself

Below is the list of log levels

[image]

Please refer there
https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#levels

Comment: I have added custom log level Trace with LevelNum 5

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not run: for example, pasting it into a source file, it fails because `f` is undefined. Commenting out that line, I got it to run without any problems. Are you *sure* that `log_setup()` is being called before the code in `xyz`? My guess is that it isn't. Also, the line

```
root.handlers = []
```

shouldn't be there - you shouldn't do this, as `handlers` is an internal attribute and not meant for you to change directly. The line

```
logging.trace = trace
```

also looks wrong, as the logging module-level convenience functions don't take an initial object argument, and have a signature such as `debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)`. Presumably you would want a module-level `trace` function to have an analogous signature.

Comment: Script from where I was calling was having call as root = logging.getLogger("TEST"). I changed this command to root = logging.getLogger("TEST."+__name) and it worked. Not sure why